# Some doubts about the event emit in Angular 2. How exactly this example works?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, javascript-framework

I am an absolute beginner with **Angular 2** and I have some doubts about how exactly works this example related how an event is emitted by the framework (I am following a tutorial).

So I have the following situation:

The main component is the **app-root** and contains this view:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <app-game-control></app-game-control>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That, as you can see, include the `<app-game-control></app-game-control>` sub component. Its view only show 2 buttons inside my single page application, these:

```
<button
  class="btn btn-success"
  (click)="onStartGame()"
>Start Game</button>

<button class="btn btn-danger">Pause Game</button>
```

Clicking on the firs one it is called the related sub component controller method **onStartGame()**, this is the entire code of this controller:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-control',
  templateUrl: './game-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-control.component.css']
})
export class GameControlComponent implements OnInit {

  intervalFired = new EventEmitter<number>();
  interval;
  lastNumber = 0;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onStartGame() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.intervalFired.emit(this.lastNumber + 1);
      this.lastNumber ++;
    }, 10000);
  }

}
```

And here I have some doubts about what exactly happens when the button is clicked.

From what I have understood an **event** is simply an object that can be emitted, in this case it should be an object containing a single numeric field:

```
intervalFired = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

Is it this interpretation of event correct or am I missing something?

When the user click the button the **onStartGame()** is performed. This method should emit the event (doing a simple calculation of its value).

But what exactly means **emit an event**? Who is the recipient of this emitted event? I think that it should be the parent component controller but I am absolutly not sure about it.

How it exactly works?

Comment: You should read the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Comment: In your current example *nothing* is receiving the event; you don't bind it in the parent template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using an `@Output()` to emit an event from a component.

Note:  `@Output() intervalFired = new EventEmitter<number>();` should be the event to be emitted.

You can handle that event in your root component as below,

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
      <app-game-control (intervalFired)="intervalFired($event)" ></app-game-control>
</div>
```

Typescript code

```
intervalFired(e){
   this.lastNumber = e;
  console.log(e)
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Za1VR9DUZ909U3Tt757a?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2):

When a component has an EventEmitter as one of its properties, it starts to emit events to the components using it. This is mostly the same as with the `button` element you used. Lets imagine the `button` is a component. It will be declared like that:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'button',
    template: '<div (click)="onButtonClick()"></div>'
})
class Button {
    click = new EventEmitter();

    onButtonClick() {
        this.click.emit(/* an event value */)
    }
}
```

Then you use this `button` component in your `GameControlComponent` by listening to the `click` event (`<button (click)="onStartGame()">`).

You can probably now understand what is emitted and who the recipient should be. In your example, the consumer of the `GameControlComponent`'s `intervalFired` event should be your `AppRoot` component, or any other component using the `<app-game-control>` component.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <app-game-control (intervalFired)="handleInterval($event)"></app-game-control>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `handleInterval` function has the `$event` argument. The value of this argument is what your internal (`GameControlComponent`) component emits, ie. `this.lastNumber + 1`.